# Git file Showing All file rewritten

Tags: git, github

I was facing serious problem earlier. Problem is that GitHub Pull Request showing files changes rewritten all files except the some changes made in existing file.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 for commit and fetch changes,
and using Command window for git pull.
If anything need more clarity, please let me know.

Steps followed:

1. `git checkout APPROVED` (My origin branch)
2. `git pull APPROVED` (My origin branch)
3. `git checkout -b in###` (Created a local branch for urgent fix )
4. Start work Then...
5. before publish to GitHub...
6. `git pull APPROVED` (My origin branch)
7. `git checkout in###` (Local branch )
8. `git merge APPROVED`
9. Commit and publish
10. complete testing and make pull request into indev

Comment: The actual problem is there , once i am making any pull request against my base branch ,  it showing file changes that i committed ,this is fine , but it looking all files is rewritten except the changes i made in that file .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do any pull request, you have to do so in a dedicated branch.

If the files appear "completely changed" when making a pull request within your own repo, this is typical of the core.autocrlf setting: if set to true, Git would change on checkout the end of lines characters automatically to CRLF.

A simple `git config --global core.autocrlf false` is enough, and is taken into account by Visual Studio

From there, make a new branch:

```
git checkout -b aNewBranch
# edit, add, commit push
```

A Pull Request done from that new branch to '`dev`' branch will show only your modifications (and *not* "everything changed").

Comment: My issue is something different , i am not getting any issue with Push and commit ,issue i am facing , when i am looking the file changes on Pull Request , it looking like all file that is published in commit is rewritten , but i have just make 2 or 3 line changes in that file ,but looking all changes .

Comment: @vivek Exactly. Hence my suggestion to start over: see if your issue persists after following my steps

Comment: it just removed all my local changes pushed in origin branch , this is not something i want to achieve . 

 may be something else going wrong .

Comment: We're your local changes committed?

Comment: Yes , i have committed changes already ,and make pull request for that as well  , 
 it is showing only committed only on origin repo , only problem is that committed files looking all code is rewritten , 
i have just make 2 line changes in working js file . i am surprised ,why it showing all files is rewritten , 
my client just cancelled all my pull request .

Comment: now i am taking checkout again of that branch and looking like ,all my changes made in previous commit are removed now by  git rebase origin branch name , right ? 
it means i have lost my changes that made earlier .

Comment: @vivek the git rebase must replay your commit on top of upstream/master: do a git log locally to confirm that: if you follow those steps, your PR will work.

Comment: ,It looking changes are removed ,it come on my previous branch , which do not have last committed files .

Comment: @vivek If you have TeamViewer installed, I can open an interactive session and have a look: http://www.teamviewer.com/

Comment: it would be a great help , add me on Skype , we can go through screen sharing . Vivekshukla406@gmail.com add me skype , i have TeamViewer as well .

Comment: @vivek No problem. I just rewritten the answer to better reflect the eol (end of line) issue

Comment: @vivek Yes, I have edited the answer already. Can you have a look?

Comment: ,yes you described well the issue ,i was facing , it really saved me , i have wasted a lot of time for fixing this , finaly we have fixed this issue .
thanks you .

Comment: same issue i am getting again , doing above steps but problem still persisting . 
problem is that core.autocrlf is showing two times now .
first core.autocrlf false and second true
that creating problem for us .

Comment: @vivek First, you can do a `git config -l --show-origin`: that will list *all* settings and will tell you where they are. Then you can edit directly the right file and remove the setting where `core.autocrlf` is set to `true`.

Comment: same things happening when i was taking update for Entity file . all my store procedure showing changes ,  i have tried to look the changes in those file then found there is one extra line that causing problem and looking all store procedures have changes . Is there setting options for this , on other machine ,there is no such problem ,

Comment: @vivek a good way to enforce that for all repos for all users on a given machine is to set the config at the system level: git config --system core.autocrlf false. Then make sure the global setting has no core.autocrlf: git config --global -l. Finally, clone a repo.

Comment: @vivek Sorry, I am no longer on holidays ;) Can you ask a new question describing the situation: I will answer it (or, more importantly, others will too)

Comment: please look this one , if more clarity needed ,please let me know , i have gone through above your comment but my problem still persisiting , please try to help me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44747909/visual-studio-update-model-from-data-base-issue

Comment: Issue with my source is fixed ,but same thing happening with my entity classes , i am getting surprised , why it happening in my case , i seeing there is no issue to others  like me .